# sympy linsolve not finding solution to system of equations

Tags: python, sympy

Can someone advise how sympy can express O as a function of (all of) O_g,O_s, O_r, O_m
where O=O_g+O_s, and O_g=O_r+O_m
?
sympy.solve() comes the closest, but I cannot access the solution expression!
sympy.**version** -> '1.1.2.dev'

```
import numpy as np;import sympy;sympy.init_printing();#help(sympy.init_printing)

O=sympy.Symbol("O")
O_g=sympy.Symbol("O_g")
O_s=sympy.Symbol("O_s")
Oe=sympy.Eq(O,O_g+O_s)
#then...
O_r=sympy.Symbol("O_r")
O_m=sympy.Symbol("O_m")
Og=sympy.Eq(O_g,O_r+O_m)

sympy.linsolve([Oe,Og],O)#empty set result

sympy.solve([Oe,Og],O)#ignores Og, as per documentation for solve

sympy.solve([Oe,Og])#give me what I want, in a dictionary along with every other possible solution...

list(_)#gives only the variables, not the solutions!
```

Comment: What exactly is your intended result?  The set {O_g, O_s, O_r, O_m} is linearly dependent, so there are infinitely many distinct ways to express O in terms of these four variables.

Comment: This is for exploratory model building. The first equation would be an expression of first principles. The second equation represents some refinement to the model. In the end, I will have data for each and every variable and I will want to numerically (least squares) solve the system using all available data. So in the example, I will have gathered data for O_r and O_m and O_s. Yes *I* can calculate O_g, but I want sympy to do that, otherwise I needn't have bothered to enter the equation. I'm doing a simple example to see how useful sympy is in terms of catching my human math error tendency.

Comment: To paraphrase my post I want to see that indeed O=Og+Or+Om. But that's a fair comment because although what I really I mean is that O_s is no longer interesting and just represents an intermediate step in the breakdown of the model, that isn't totally obvious from the way I entered the equations.  SFTP has suggested the correct approach though I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot access the solution expression

What's the problem with accessing the values in a dictionary?

```
sol = sympy.solve([Oe, Og])
print(sol[O])
```

With `sympy.linsolve([Oe,Og],O)`, the problem is one of equations does not have any of the variables you are solving for, so it's impossible  to express a solution. Something like

```
sympy.linsolve([Oe,Og], [O, O_g])
```

or

```
sympy.linsolve([Oe,Og], [O, O_r])
```

works fine.

Comment: sol is a set, not an array, so it would have to be list(sol)[0]. And there is no expression of (any) solution in that array.

Comment: Yes I see, linsolve will incorporate every equation, as long as you ask for solutions to every (or at least one) variable. Thanks SFTP!

Comment: Though I'm curious @SFTP, why you downvoted this (if it was you). The question was clear enough for it to have been answered. And concise enough not to waste anybodies time if they don't know how the sympy solvers work.